# PostgreSQL No Mapping between account name and security IDs

Tags: postgresql

I  downloaded the installation file on https://www.postgresql.org/. I have Windows 10. As soon as I click on the installer of PostgreSQL, I face an issue:
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYmvh.png)

[Image of the version of Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjMam.png)
Do somebody know where to look for the solution? Thanks. I tried tens of ways, nothing helps. I tried to make some some changes in Windows log files, I changed user, I tried to open through the administrator rights and others ways.

Comment: Move to dba.stackexchange.com _and_ use `[postgres]` instead of the other db tags.

Comment: Postgres needs to change their installer. There's better ways to grant permissions to a file than using a command line executable which is subject to the vagaries of regional settings. Speaking of that, you may want to include what release of Windows 10 (English/Russian/etc), and if the Language for non-Unicode programs is set.

Comment: yes, I can't install trough command prompt as well. Sorry, where should I include the release of Windows 10 and Where should I change the language in my PC? Is it in language settings? I have english set there everywhere. Thanks

Comment: I suppose this is actually not just "language", but all the regional preferences, a.k.a. "the locale". The decimals point, for example, is "." in some locales and "," in another; date formatting differs, and so on. Poorly written installers could choke on some of those differences. // And, to be honest, Postgres performance in Windows seems to be *mediocre*. Just tested that. Same HW, same workload, when Postgres is running in Linux, we achieved overall 60% more (not all attributed to Postfix, but still it has its share in this).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I need choose English, not Ukrainin while reinstalling windows. Becuase on another computer where English was from the start, the installation works fine.